# MEAN stack DELETE not working - What is electionId?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, express, mean-stack

I'm using Angular4, Express 4.15 and Node 7.9.
My GET, POST, PUT requests are working all fine.. but i'm not sure why the delete function is not working. I used Mlab for my mongodb, and mongojs to make the connection.

**Edit - On Postman, doing i DELETE request i get an electionId which i don't understand (see below)**

I don't see any errors, and i get a 200 response code when i click the delete button.[image]

Here is the front-end -

```
<td><input (click)="deleteCandidate(candidate)" type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" value="Delete"></td>
```

The function in my component -

```
deleteCandidate(candidate){
  var candidates = this.candidates;

  this._candidateService.removeCandidate(candidate._id)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    if(data.n == 1){
      for(var i = 0; i < candidates.length; i++){
        if(candidates[i]._id == candidate._id){
          candidates.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

And the corresponding service  -

```
removeCandidate(id)
    {
        return this._http.delete('/api/v1/candidate/'+id);  
    }
```

And here is the route for ExpressJS (i've used mongojs) -

```
// Delete a candidate
router.delete('/candidate/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    db.candidates.remove({
        _id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.param.id)
    }, '', function(err, result) {
            if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Edit - Just tried doing a DELETE request from Postman and it does not succeed. I get the following response -

```
{
  "ok": 1,
  "n": 0,
  "opTime": {
    "ts": "6418646173661265921",
    "t": 1
  },
  "electionId": "7fffffff0000000000000001"
}
```

Your help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: "Not working" is too vague... what isn't working? Where the item isn't being deleted? On front or back end?

Comment: @developer033 , on both ends. I just checked on Postman and i can't delete it from there too. This might be a backend thing. This is the response i get from postman - {
  "ok": 1,
  "n": 0,
  "opTime": {
    "ts": "6418646173661265921",
    "t": 1
  },
  "electionId": "7fffffff0000000000000001"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"n": 0` in the response means that the database query didn't match any documents. In this case it is probably cause you wrote `req.param.id` instead of `req.params.id`.